# Higher-order function in functional programming with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to learn functional programming in JavaScript, and I can't wrap my head around this higher-order function. I don't understand why calling `g(1,2,3,4)` results in `[1]`. I tried doing `console.log("arg: ", arg)` as below, and I don't understand why `arg` in the `console.log` is `1`. Where does `arg` come from? How is `arg` passed to `funcation one(arg)`? Does it have anything to do with curry? Can someone explain it in a very simple and beginning level way?

```
function unary(fn) {
        return function one(arg) {
        console.log("arg: ", arg)
            return fn(arg)
        }
}

function f(...args) {
    return args
}
    
var g =  unary(f)
g(1,2,3,4) // [1]
```

Comment: The example is a bit strange. It’s passing four arguments to a function that only accepts one and ignores the rest. _“Where does `arg` come from?”_ — It’s the `1` from `g(1,2,3,4)`. This call is equivalent to `g(1)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where in the functions are 2,3 and 4 shopped out?

Comment: You could also return the `function one(arg1, arg2, arg3) { return fn(arg) }` to make it more clear where the other arguments go

Comment: Look at the type to get rid of the noise (pseudo annotation): `unary :: (a -> b) -> a -> b`. `unary` takes a function `(a -> b)` as an argument and returns another function `a -> b`. This other function takes an argument `a` and applies it with the function argument. The other arguments are just ignored. `unary` is thus an applicator that enforces a single argument.